# Adding multiple values for a specific user in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to add multiple values under a specific row for a user. It would look similar to this:

| User | Departments |
| --- | --- |
| John | Deli |
| John | Frozen Goods |
| John | Bakery |

So far, I am having to add in these values individually and manually, is there a way to add all departments under on user in a single SQL statement?

**Update**
Here is a snippet of code I have so far. With this, it creates a comma separated list for departments, but I would rather just have the user listed multiple times and a different department assigned to each of those instances.

```
 department = "," + department + ",";
            department = department.Replace(",,", ",");
            department = department.Replace(",,", ",");
            department = department.Replace(",,", ",");
            department = department.Replace(",,", ",");
            strsql = "UPDATE [TV_App].[dbo].[users] " +
                "SET " +
                 "[u_FirstName] = '" + firstname + "' " +
                    ",[u_LastName] = '" + lastname + "' " +
                    ",[u_Admin] = " + admrights +
                    ",[u_Departments] = '" + department + "'" +
                    ",[u_LastEditedOn] = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "'" +
                    ",[u_LastEditedBy] = '" + username + "' " +
                "WHERE [u_ADUN] = '" + username + "' " +
                "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 " +
                "INSERT INTO [TV_App].[dbo].[users] " +
                "( " +
                   "[u_ADUN] " + ",[u_FirstName] " + ",[u_LastName] " +
                      ",[u_Admin] " + ",[u_Departments] " +
                      ",[u_CreatedOn] " + ",[u_CreatedBy] " +
                      ",[u_LastEditedOn] " + ",[u_LastEditedBy] " +
                      ",[u_LastLoginOn] " + ",[u_LastLoginFrom] " +
                      ",[u_FirstLoginOn] " + ",[u_FirstLoginFrom] " +
                      ",[u_UsageCount] " +
                 ") VALUES( " +
                        "'" + username + "', " + "'" + firstname + "', " + "'" + lastname + "', " +
                             admrights + ", '" + department + "', " +
                        "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', " + "'" + Environment.UserName.ToLower() + "', " +
                        "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', " + "'" + Environment.UserName.ToLower() + "', " +
                        "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', 'newuser', " +
                        "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "', 'newuser', " +
                        "0" +
                  ") ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            return;
```

Additional information: I am adding these items from a checked listbox.

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far? I mean, you could just use a regular loop, for one...

Comment: Yikes, this is crazy vulnerable to sql injection issues. You need to **drop everything** and learn how to use parameterized queries before you do anything else. This is that important.

Comment: A Table Valued Parameter is probably the best option, combine that with either `MERGE` or `UPDATE...; INSERT...WHERE NOT EXISTS...;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server allows you to use a [Table-Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-inserting-multiple-rows-of-data), like this:

```
INSERT INTO [table]
(User, Departments)
VALUES 
('John', 'Deli'),
('John', 'Frozen Goods'),
('John', 'Bakery')
```

Given the C# tag (and now code after the edit), it seems you also want to do this from client code. There are  a few options here. For example, you can use [the `SqlLBulkCopy` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), or you can use a [Table-Value parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). And you can also, of course, execute multiple insert queries in a loop, where the only thing that changes on each iteration is the value of the parameters (for a few rows, this isn't as bad as it seems).

---

Yikes. Now I can see the code it is apparent the issues run far deeper. I'll ignore the UPSERT pattern for now, but I need to show you better patterns for how to handle the rest of this:

```cs
strsql = @"
UPDATE [TV_App].[dbo].[users] 
   SET [u_FirstName] = @firstname, [u_LastName] = @lastname,
       [u_Admin] = @admrights, [u_Departements] = @department,
       [u_LastEditedOn] = current_timestamp,
       [u_LastEditedBy] = @username
WHERE [u_ADUN] = @username;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
INSERT INTO [TV_App].[dbo].[users]
(
    [u_ADUN], [u_FirstName], [u_LastName], [u_Admin], 
    [u_Departments], [u_CreatedOn], [u_CreatedBy],
    [u_LastEditedOn], [u_LastEditedBy], [u_LastLoginOn],
    [u_LastLoginFrom], [u_FirstLoginOn], [u_FirstLoginFrom],
    [u_UsageCount]
) VALUES (
    @username, @firstname, @lastname, @admrights,
    @department, current_timestamp, @myusername,
    current_timestamp, @myusername, current_timestamp,
    'newuser', @curTime, 'newuser', 0
);";


// do NOT try to re-use the same connection object throughout your app!
using var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here");
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(strsql, conn);

//use actual column types and lengths from the database for each of these parameters
cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = firstname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = lastname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@admRights", SqlDbType.Char, 5).Value = admrights; //looks more like a flag/code than arbitrary string
cmd.Parameters.Add("@department", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = department;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = username;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@myusername", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = Environment.UserName.ToLower();
//this could also have used current_timestamp, but I wanted to demonstrate a DateTime parameter.
// I especially wanted to demonstrate you NEVER need to convert to a string value.
// And, in fact, even the string values you were using were the WRONG FORMAT for SQL.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@curTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;


conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //ExecuteReader? for an UPDATE/INSERT? No.
// No need to close the connection. The `using` directive takes care of it.
```

This won't fix the whole problem. It's still using the same `department` variable from above. Unfortunately, we don't see enough about how that value is built to correct that part of the issue. Additionally, while I commend you wanting to separate out the individual department values (csv values in a single column are *really bad*), this probably belongs with a **separate table** (called a junction or intersection table) to connect these together, rather than duplicating the entire `users` record.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! Still fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use multiple list of value with sql statement

```
INSERT INTO `s`(`username`, `role`) VALUES ('jone','Deli'),('jone','Frozen Goods') ,('jone','Bakery');
```